# Facebook limits my reach when I have a history of paying to promote or boost a post?

Tags: facebook

Is it true that Facebook limits your audience reach AFTER you've paid to promote or boost a post because they know you'll pay them again to promote?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's true.

First Facebook shows that your post reaching to many people and can reach to bigger audience if you boost or promote your post. Once you pay for that then they limit it, and wait for you to pay more.

Audience limit is depends on your budget. Facebook select the audience based on your budget:

[image]

Comment: I know I'm probably over simplifying it but I think that if someone "likes" your Facebook page, your posts should show up in their news feed according to chronological order (date/time posted) and not intentionally omitted by Facebook because Facebook wants the page owner to pay to boost or promote. Kind of frustrating.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It should show up in the followers feed, and it show up but not actively as it show up in case of boost page. So the main motive of Facebook that page owner should promote their posts.